# Using Parse REST API to link an uploaded image to a parse object, getting access denied when accessing image

Tags: rest, parse-platform

I'm using the sample code provided in the REST API docs for uploading an image (my own) and then assigning it to an object in an image table. Image uploads fine, code for associating the image runs fine, and a record is created in the DB.

However, if I try to access the image from the data browser, I get ACCESS DENIED. Why is this so? The image is retrievable via the URL provided after a successful upload, but doesn't appear anywhere in the Parse web UI (should it be ihe Files section of Cloud Code?).

Any input would be helpful. I am working on a few wrinkles to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is to use the long filename provided in the image upload confirm, and not the short filename example shown in the docs.